ClassNotFoundError: on app launch: Spring Boot 3, springdoc, Gradle
I'm trying to start up a simple REST server (Spring Boot 3, Spring Web).
I'm used to Maven, but this time I had to use Gradle. Never had business with it before.
I may have messed up the setup. Once I launch the application, I get a flurry of errors.
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [org.springdoc.webmvc.ui.SwaggerConfig] from ClassLoader [jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@1d44bcfa]

Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/web/servlet/resource/LiteWebJarsResourceResolver

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.LiteWebJarsResourceResolver

Execution failed for task ':com.example.socks_api.SocksApiApplication.main()'.
> Process 'command 'C:\Users\nadch\.jdks\corretto-17.0.13\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.
BUILD FAILED in 17s
3 actionable tasks: 3 executed

As I believe everything else is irrelevant, I only share my build.gradle.kts file (I may share other information if necessary).
plugins {
    java
    id("org.springframework.boot") version "3.3.7"
    id("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.1.7"
}

group = "com.example"
version = "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"

java {
    toolchain {
        languageVersion = JavaLanguageVersion.of(17)
    }
}

configurations {
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom(configurations.annotationProcessor.get())
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    implementation("org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui:2.7.0")
    implementation("org.mapstruct:mapstruct:1.6.3")
    runtimeOnly("org.postgresql:postgresql")
    compileOnly("org.projectlombok:lombok")
    annotationProcessor("org.projectlombok:lombok")
    annotationProcessor("org.mapstruct:mapstruct-processor:1.6.3")
    annotationProcessor("org.projectlombok:lombok-mapstruct-binding:0.2.0")
    testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
    testRuntimeOnly("org.junit.platform:junit-platform-launcher")
}

tasks.withType<Test> {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

This simialar question suggests it may have to do with springdoc. However, as you may see, I do include the right dependency and do not include springdoc-openapi-ui.
How do I resolve this problem?

I could not reproduce the error by just using deps from your question and Spring Boot 3.4.1, hence I believe the cause is something not shown in your question. BR

Gradle/Lombok tip: With plugin id("io.freefair.lombok") version "8.11", you can simplify your dependencies.
